# Javascript global array declaration

Tags: javascript, arrays, global-variables

I am writing a function that takes a parameter as a word and saves it to an array.
Each time the function is called I want it to give me all the existing elements in an array.
For eg,
var addA = add("a");
var addb = add("b");

I have declared a global array but when I call the array inside the function it says undefined,

```
var arr = [];
function add(element) {
  arr.push(element);
}
```

I am new to JS any help would be appreciated?.

Comment: Google "JavaScript return statement"

Comment: Don't you already have access to them in the form of the global array? or do you want to make a new copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is this,

```
var arr = [];
var addA = add("a"); 
function add(element) {
  arr.push(element);
  return arr;
}
```

The way this works is that the element is pushed to the array and then the entire array with the new element is returned from the function.